# IP Address and threats

Tags: ip

This will be an atypical question. My daughter was recently threatened over the internet(the content of which this site will not allow). We have attempted to work with the local police who know less than us (not a good start).

The Comcast IP address which the threat originated from is in Minneapolis.  I have requested this small town PD pass a request on to Minneapolis because they would have cyber crime people who would be more proficient. I do know that sooner would be better than later with collecting potential data which may be evidence. If a threat is sent over a Comcast IP address is there an easy way to assess if data collection is even an option. I do not want to throw the IP address into the public sphere on the chance that law enforcement may be involved in the future (hopefully) and someone who knows more than I might unintentionally interfere. I have patiently waited for several days and know that Comcast will only work with law enforcement.

Anyone have any ideas? Please jump in.

Comment: So you have the IP address and want to "collect data"? What do you mean by this exactly?

Comment: There really isn't a whole lot you can get from just an IP address. The ISP will likely have some records as to who was using it and that information can be obtained with a subpoena, but that is probably the only useful information to be gathered. With proper warrants, the police could do further monitoring with the help of the ISP.

Comment: Eric.  By "collect data" I mean the following: Realizing that the two parties (victim and small police dept) involved with this at the moment have no idea what is possible is a bit frustrating.  Maybe nothing is possible.  About all I can tell you is that a crime has occurred facilitated through a network I know nothing about.  My initial questions is: Is potential useful data present somewhere which would be evidence?  If the answer is yes, how do you convey this to the police who do not understand the system.

Comment: Maybe another question to start with would be: Based on the fact that it is a Comcast IP address wireless network, would there be a way to determine if the network originates at a free wifi network(which it sounds like would be a waste of time to try to follow up on) Or could someone determine if it goes to a private residence which might be productive for the perpetrator to at least be questioned by the police. (if nothing more) Thank you for your responses...it helps just to get some basic understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind IP addresses do not identify people, they are properties of machines or networks.

Any ISP can know and track which endpoint (in Comcast's case, a cable modem) had a specific IP address at a specific time, and that can be correlated with account info.  From there a location can be determined.  Hopefully it's not something like a restuarant with free Wi-fi or a store where the open public Wi-fi is decent from the parking lot.

They of course would likely not give this information to you without a court order.  I'm not sure of any requirement of Comcast to retain or log this information, if they do it's probably for diagnostic or internal purposes.

Even if you know the location of the originating IP, the contact there may merely say "well, my system has been acting strange, it may have been hacked, your attacker might be in one of them crazy other countries.  I'll run an antivirus and hope that takes care of things."  Which is a possibility.  Just illustrating that knowing the IP is usually only a part of the puzzle in finding out who did an attack over the Internet.

If the attack was something that was done through an online service, such as Facebook, email, or something else that requires sign up, you should reach out to any abuse/security contacts provided by that service and report the account and behavior in question.